# Fisher’s Score based feature selection

Tags: python

I am trying to select the best feature based on Fisher's score. In the following code, X_train and y_train are pandas dataframe.

```
from skfeature.function.similarity_based import fisher_score
ranks = fisher_score.fisher_score(X_train, y_train)
V = X_train.columns[ranks[:5]]
print(V)
```

The above code is giving the error Length of values (1) does not match the length of index (13).

But if I convert the data frame into NumPy array, then the code is executing. The following code is executing perfectly.

```
from skfeature.function.similarity_based import fisher_score
ranks = fisher_score.fisher_score(np.array(X_train), np.array(y_train))
V = X_train.columns[ranks[:5]]
print(V)
```

But the above code is making kernel dead, probably because of large size of numpy array. Is there any way to solve this without using Numpy array or any other way where I may not face kernel dead issue.